# LEGO Mindstorms NXT 2.0 "Clicking Brick Syndrome"

Tags: lego-mindstorms

First of all, this may sound like a duplicate post. But, my Mindstorms NXT 2.0 has been having the "Clicking Brick Syndrome". I have been told that uninstalling the bossa driver then unplugging and replugging the brick offline will cause it to install correctly. Unfortunately this does not happen and the bossa drivers reinstall. Anyone have any ideas that may help? If it matters i am running windows 10.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "bossa" driver. Do you mean the "Fantom" driver available at http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/ ?

Comment: Also, stackoverflow is for programming questions, so this question is a bit off topic. It seems a better fit to ask at http://bricks.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks... I reposted this on the lego stack exchange